# Why did my avatar change here on meta, even if my email didn't?

Tags: support, gravatar, email, profile-page, images

I'm 100% sure it never was yellow.. Anyone else's changed?

Comment: Your meta profile is showing it now. Your super user account should have the exact same issue. After that, you should be all set.

Comment: Closing as no longer relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no email address set on your meta account. Update your meta profile information with your email used with gravatar and you should see your picture.

Should be the same story with your Super User account also.

Comment: Ohhh, so it uses my username instead? Makes sense since I recently changed my username. I thought having an email was mandatory and that it was automatically taken from openid.. I see I was wrong though. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Gravatar is based off your email address, so you want to use the email you have a gravatar image associated with. So, set your accounts to the same email address you used on your SF and SO accounts.  I see your picture ok on those accounts.